# How to import NumPy as a module into Eclipse (PyDev)

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, import

I'm trying to use NumPy in Eclipse, in which I'm using Python 3.4 and PyDev.  I have installed NumPy version 1.9.2 (with setup.py) and it works fine in IDLE

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
>>>print(a)
[0 1 2 3]
```

but when I do the same thing in Eclipse I get an error `No Module named 'numpy'`

I have already gone to Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter > Libraries

and added the NumPy location `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy` and restarted my machine.

I'm at a loss for what to try next, do I need to delete and reconfigure all of PyDev in order for this to work?

Comment: If you're using Python 3.4, how did NumPy get installed to the 3.5 stdlib? It sounds like you may have installed both 3.4 and 3.5alpha, and then installed NumPy for 3.5 only, and you're using the 3.5 IDLE, but your PyDev is configured for 3.4. Different Python installations have their own separate site-packages, and if you want to use two Pythons, and use the same packages in both, you have to install it for both.

Comment: Also, why did you install manually NumPy with `setup.py` instead of using `pip`? That's probably not related here, but using `pip` whenever possible will make your life easier in a lot of ways.

Comment: I didn't know about `pip`, you're absolutely right, I was running 3.5 on the terminal, but 3.4 in Eclipse.  Installing NumPy with `pip3.4` solved the problem instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a Python 3.4 installation, which you're using in PyDev, and a Python 3.5 installation, which you're using in the terminal. Each one has its own separate site-packages. So, when you installed NumPy by running its setup.py with a Python 3.5, it got installed into the 3.5 site-packages, but when you went looking for it in PyDev, it wasn't in the 3.4 site-packages.

You can see the version number 3.5 right there in the output you provided. However, if you want to be absolutely sure, you can `print(sys.version)` from inside PyDev and from on the terminal.

At any rate, the solution is to do any of the following:

1. Install NumPy for 3.4 as well. You can do this by running `python3.4 setup.py install` (the same as you did for 3.5 but with `python3.4` instead of just `python3`). However, if `pip3.4 install numpy` works, this is usually better.
2. Configure PyDev to use 3.5 instead of 3.4.
3. Uninstall either 3.4 or 3.5. You'll still have to do one of the above as well, but this will make it impossible to get wrong, and reduce the chances of you getting similarly confused again in the future.

---

If you're wondering why this didn't help:

> ... and added the NumPy location /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy

The problem is that you added `site-packages/numpy` instead of just `site-packages`. There's no package named `numpy` inside the `numpy` package.

However, you don't want to fix things by adding the 3.5 site-packages to the 3.4 search path; many packages, especially those that require compiled C code like `numpy`, won't work with a version of Python different from the one they were installed for.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Eclipse is using the correct Python interpreter with,

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

At the start of the program.  If it returns anything other than what you've expected you've likely installed it to the wrong Python version.